# Error replacing a column with other values data frames R

Tags: r, dataframe, error-handling, intersection, factors

I'm trying to replace the values which I've set by default in a data frame by the calculated ones but I get an error that I don't understand as far as I've no factors.

Here is the code :

```
nb_agences_iris <- agences %>%


group_by(CODE_IRIS) %>%
  summarise(nb_agences = n()) %>%
  arrange(CODE_IRIS)

int <- data.frame("CODE_IRIS" = as.character(intersect(typo$X0, nb_agences_iris$CODE_IRIS)))
typo$nb_agences <- as.character(rep(0, nrow(typo)))
typo[int$CODE_IRIS,]$nb_agences <- as.character(nb_agences_iris[int$CODE_IRIS,]$nb_agences)
```

And I get the following error:

```
Error in Summary.factor(1:734, na.rm = FALSE) : 
  ‘max’ not meaningful for factors
In addition: Warning message:
In Ops.factor(i, 0L) : ‘>=’ not meaningful for factors
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Can you show (at least part of) `agences` ? Use `dput` to keep structure.

Comment: I can't but it's a simple df with 918 rows and 26 columns of all types